# Recovering lost Visual studio 2010 solution after VS update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I worked a few hours building a new solution in Visual Studio 2010 (C#). Created the solution, built and debugged a bunch of times, saved regularly using ctrl+S... AutoRecover is set to save every 5 minutes as well.

Windows was installing a VS 2010 update and rebooted automatically, forcing a shut down.

On restart, the whole solution was gone. The only traces I can find are an empty folder with the solution's name in the "backup" folder and 2 early built located in "*C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VCSExpress\10.0\ProjectAssemblies\fh5gnjqk01*" which I think were created when the build failed.

Is there any chance that newer files are still there somewhere in some temp folder or something, or should I just consider it lost and move on? Since I built and debugged the solution, I suspect there must be a newer ".exe" somewhere that I could reuse with reflector if nothing else.

If not, what should I do in the future to guarantee that the solution is really saved on the disk?

Comment: Source control is what you need to do. :) It will help minimise the loss of code. You code something, it works, check it in, rinse lather repeat. Where was the project saved? It's totally gone from there I assume? It's usually in a "Visual Studio 2010" folder in your My Documents/Documents folder. Perhaps you have hardware issues if the update failed, do you know what update it was?

Comment: I'm no filesystem expert but if a simple search for one of your .cs files doesnt show anything I would consider it lost and move on. Doubt why it wasnt saved with all your ctrl-ses though.

Comment: @Arran Yeah, I normally use source control, but that was a single 4 hours coding session on a new project and I usually set-up Git afterwards. It's definitely not in the project folder.

Comment: @allen Nope, file search only turns up what I already found, so I guess that's that, but I am having difficulties figuring out why the problem happened in the first place.